# Как добраться до cart_informer?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

В чем весь сабж, есть код :

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>111</li>
<li class="cart_informer">
</li>
```

Чтобы добраться до 111, нужно сделать так:

```
$('#menu > li')
```

А что нужно сделать, чтобы добраться до cart_informer?

дополнение:
    <!-- Меню -->
    <ul id="menu">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var d = 300;
            $('#menu a').each(function () {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop': '-80px'
                }, d += 150);
            });

```
        $('#menu > li').hover(

        function () {
            $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '-2px'
            }, 200);
        },

        function () {
            $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '-80px'
            }, 200);
        });
    });
</script>

{foreach $pages as $p}
    {* Выводим только страницы из первого меню *}
    {if $p->menu_id == 1}
    <li {if $page && $page->id == $p->id}class="selected"{/if}>
        <a data-page="{$p->id}" href="{$p->url}">{$p->name|escape}</a>
    </li>
    {/if}
{/foreach}   
   <li class="cart_informer">
       {include file='cart_informer.tpl'}
   </li>
</ul>
<!-- Меню (The End) -->
```

А это код пункта корзина :

```
$('form.variants').live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
    if ($(this).find('input[name=variant]:checked').size() > 0) variant = $(this).find('input[name=variant]:checked').val();
    if ($(this).find('select[name=variant]').size() > 0) variant = $(this).find('select').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/cart.php",
        data: {
            variant: variant
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#menu > li.cart_informer').html(data);
            if (button.attr('data-result-text')) button.val(button.attr('data-result-text'));
        }
    });
    var o1 = $(this).offset();
    var o2 = $('#menu > li.cart_informer').offset();
    var dx = o1.left - o2.left;
    var dy = o1.top - o2.top;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    $(this).closest('.product').find('.image img').effect("transfer", {
        to: $('#menu > li.cart_informer'),
        className: "transfer_class"
    }, distance);
    $('.transfer_class').html($(this).closest('.product').find('.image').html());
    $('.transfer_class').find('img').css('height', '100%');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$('#menu > li.cart_informer')

а вообще есть оч полезный для начинающего ресурс на русском: http://jquery.page2page.ru

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще и вот так:

```
var $menu_li = $('#menu > li');

$menu_li.eq(0) - <li>111</li>

$menu_li.eq(1) - <li class="cart_informer"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Через `$('#menu > li)` вы получите все дочерние `li`, а не только первый.
Что-то вроде `$('#menu .cart_informer')` вернет вам все `li.cart_informer`.
А еще вам могут помочь `.last()`, `:last-child`, `:nth-child()` и т.д., и т.п.

**upd:**
Теперь понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Наведение вам надо вешать на все пункты меню, кроме корзины:

```
$('#menu > li').not('.cart_informer').hover(.. // или как там у вас оно
// здесь ищем все дочерние li, у которых нет класса cart_informer
```

А для корзины что-то своё:

```
$('#menu > .cart_informer')... // действия
// тут наоборот - все дочерние элементы с классом cart_informer
```

*Не обделяйте вниманием [документацию](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).*

Comment: Сложность в том, что я совершенно не знаю джаву, а учить нету времени. Поэтому и прошу помощи. Основная задача сделать горизонтальное меню вот такого типа
    http://i51.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0228/df/d5e6fee48e67821cb57a3d5371b0c2df.png

Comment: При наведении курсора меню должно выпадать в низ...Но там еще есть корзина...у нее еще есть одна особенность. при нажатии кнопки "в корзину" - изображение товара летит к меню.а точнее к пункту "корзина"...когда изображение туда долетает.вкладка корзина раскрывается и остается на месте раскрытой....то есть не сворачивается назад.Как можно сделать что бы она либо не разворачивалась...либо сворачивалась после этого?....P.S добавил код в первом посте

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: нет...корзина должна иметь такие же свойства что и все категории в меню + свои св-ва....все работает-но после того как товар долетает до корзины она выпадает и не сворачивается назад...

Comment: @HoPkInS, и хотя вы не автор вопроса, мой ответ будет таким же - все инструменты, даже с примерами, представлены в моём ответе

О каких свойствах вообще идёт речь? Корзина тоже должна выпадать вниз? Так уберите исключение по классу.

Comment: Считайте что я автор.это первое.второе-автор как и я обсолютно не знает js.даже как переменную присвоить.и вы предлагаете учить js что бы сделать меню?я понятия не имею как убирать исключения и т.д....и да.корзина при наведении тоже должна падать вниз

Comment: Тогда вам нужен фрилансер. Точка.

Answer (score -1):

Самый быстрый вариант:

```
var cartInformer = $('#menu').children('.cart_informer');
```

Comment: Это что?. Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Вы спросили: "А что нужно сделать, чтобы добраться до cart_informer?"

Это ответ. Самый быстрый из jquery при условии что у вас один .cart_infromer, а не несколько.